# Flash AS3 Grid color transparent?

Tags: actionscript-3, grid, flash-cs6

I need a grid to move stuff around on but the grid itself remains visible.
Is there a hexcode or a fade method to still have it present but invisible?

```
var grid:Sprite = Sprite(addChild(new Sprite()));
grid.graphics.lineStyle(0,0x000000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var grid:Sprite = new Sprite;

addChild(grid);

// Third argument is alpha.
grid.graphics.lineStyle(0, 0x000000, 0);
```